# printf() with incomplete parameter list

Tags: c

I was solving C programming Questions and I came across this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int x=100,y=200,z=300;
   printf("%d..%d..%d");
}
```

I expected an error but the output was `300..200..100`

Can anyone explain this output?

Comment: Undefined behaviour can cause all sorts of results, even some that somehow look desirable.

Comment: Generally, this is undefined behavior. But since x,y,z are on the stack before printf call, this works. Don't try this at home...

Comment: Read about calling conventions, specifically cdecl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: OP expected an error and got one, just not the error expected. The result is UB - undefined behavior.  C does not define what undefined behavior should occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` in `printf` expects `int` type argument. You are passing no arguments. Its a constraint violation and ultimately your program invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @shashank; There may be chocolates and pizza too!

Comment: _undefined behavior_ means _anything_ can happen, including printing out "300..200..100".

Answer (score 1):

your code has so many warning says..

```
root@jeegar:~/test# gcc -Wall testprintf.c 
testprintf.c: In function ‘main’:
testprintf.c:5:4: warning: too few arguments for format
testprintf.c:4:20: warning: unused variable ‘z’
testprintf.c:4:14: warning: unused variable ‘y’
testprintf.c:4:8: warning: unused variable ‘x’
testprintf.c:6:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

when i run your code it shows different result each time.

```
root@jeegar:~/test# ./a.out 
1822880072..1822880088..4195632root@jeegar:~/test# 
root@jeegar:~/test# 
root@jeegar:~/test# ./a.out 
-1388515512..-1388515496..4195632root@jeegar:~/test# 
root@jeegar:~/test# 
root@jeegar:~/test# 
root@jeegar:~/test# ./a.out 
401499528..401499544..4195632root@jeegar:~/test#
```

So here it's  **undefined behavior**

It may be posible that undefined behavior result same value as yours

Answer (score 0):

When you use "%d" you are saying that a integer input should go there, but you never supply the integer to use. You need to add the integers as arguments after the string, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int x=100,y=200,z=300;
   printf("%d..%d..%d", x, y, z);
}
```

If you run `printf("%d..%d..%d");` you will still get an output, but it will be some random un-initialized values.

Comment: "If you run printf("%d..%d..%d"); you will **may** still get an output".  It is undefined behavior, program could crash instead.

Answer (score 0):

printf is

```
int printf(const char*, ...)
```

a function with variable number of arguments. printf identify number of arguments using const char string - it count number of % signs. It takes first argument after const char argument and walks down the stack. It occasionally happened that local variables are situated just under function frame. But on other compilers and with other directives you will get other results, because in this case behaviour is undefined. For example, on my computer I get 0, 100, 200. On win VSE I get 0..0..random number in debug mode and rand.. 0 .. rand in release mode, etc.